# Free Pager and Contextual filter

Tags: views, nodes

I just can't get my head around the following problem.

- I have two content types. One is **ISSUE** the other one is **ARTICLE**.
- I use the *Node Reference module* to link and **ARTICLE** to an **ISSUE**.
- Then I am using *Free Pager module* to have a pager on every page to click to the next and previous node.

The pager works but for all **ARTICLES** of all **ISSUES**. Now I want it to work for only the **ARTICLES** in the same **ISSUE** as the current node.

I tried to get this to work with the normal Views filter and the Contextual filter but for some reason it doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution for this? Or another option with other modules that do the trick?

Thanks in advance
Joost

Comment: it should work easily in Views with a simple exposed filter - are you using the reference field in Article or Issue to link the two? what filter criterion are you using for the filter?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Reference Node in Article to link the two. I'm filtering on Content Type [Article] and Published [Yes].

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Views:

- set up the view in the format you want so that all Articles show
- create a filter on the Node Reference Field in Content:Articles
- expose this filter
- make the operator: Is one of
- Options: Select all - this should automatically update as new issues are created
- Pager: Mini, Mini pager, 1 item - this will create a simple pager with only one item per page

Comment: Hi Geoff, thanks! But I don't want the filter to be exposed it should automatically filter/show the nodes that have the same related node as the current node.

Comment: then change that to a contextual filter, the principle remains the same... otherwise you would need to get into session variables and a custom module I think

Comment: Okay, this is an option but changes my complete way of how my site works. This way I'm making a view with a pager. But I want to show a node with a pager block. How is this possible?

Comment: with a custom module, that will essentially do what Views is doing in my answer

Comment: Thanks, so a custom module, I'll see if I can figure out how. Never made one but I'll try my best.

Comment: since the pager module works to some extent, I would suggest copying it and using that as a starting point - you would just need to add a check on the next and prev content to make sure it meets the same criteria as the current node